# Adding audio player to a node in SceneKit

Tags: swift, scenekit, audio-player

I have some problems with adding an audio player to a node. For some reason, I get an exception and my application stops. Here is how my code looks like

```
    let node = scene.rootNode.childNodeWithName("box", recursively: true)!

    let source = SCNAudioSource(fileNamed: "test.mp3")
    source.loops = true
    source.volume = 2
    source.positional = true
    source.shouldStream = true
    source.load()
    let player = SCNAudioPlayer(source: source)

    node.addAudioPlayer(player)
```

Can anybody help me find out what is the problem?

**Edit:** Exception:

2015-06-12 10:44:29.202 asd[10480:2157476] 10:44:29.202 ERROR:    AVAudioNodeImpl.h:39: AVAE_CheckNodeHasEngine: required condition is false: _engine != nil
2015-06-12 10:44:29.208 asd[10480:2157476] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'com.apple.coreaudio.avfaudio', reason: 'required condition is false: _engine != nil'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010ca18885 **exceptionPreprocess + 165
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010e9afdf1 objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010ca186ea +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 106
    3   libAVFAudio.dylib                   0x0000000115549efe libAVFAudio.dylib + 98046
    4   libAVFAudio.dylib                   0x000000011558b4fd libAVFAudio.dylib + 365821
    5   libAVFAudio.dylib                   0x000000011558aaa5 libAVFAudio.dylib + 363173
    6   SceneKit                            0x000000010d3695eb C3DTransactionFlush + 1967
    7   SceneKit                            0x000000010d3699e9 C3DTransactionCommit + 218
    8   SceneKit                            0x000000010d2f7f6e -[SCNRenderer setPointOfView:] + 4677
    9   SceneKit                            0x000000010d2f8c05 -[SCNRenderer setScene:completionHandler:] + 213
    10  SceneKit                            0x000000010d354920 -[SCNView setScene:] + 319
    11  asd                                 0x000000010c8338b2 _TFC3asd18GameViewController11viewDidLoadfS0_FT_T_ + 2866
    12  asd                                 0x000000010c833ba2 _TToFC3asd18GameViewController11viewDidLoadfS0_FT_T_ + 34
    13  UIKit                               0x000000010d7bbd65 -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 860
    14  UIKit                               0x000000010d7bc0b4 -[UIViewController view] + 27
    15  UIKit                               0x000000010d69f3d4 -[UIWindow addRootViewControllerViewIfPossible] + 61
    16  UIKit                               0x000000010d69fad1 -[UIWindow _setHidden:forced:] + 302
    17  UIKit                               0x000000011c867717 UIKit + 247575
    18  UIKit                               0x000000010d6b0ff8 -[UIWindow makeKeyAndVisible] + 43
    19  UIKit                               0x000000010d63302b -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesForMainScene:transitionContext:] + 3545
    20  UIKit                               0x000000010d638ef0 -[UIApplication _runWithMainScene:transitionContext:completion:] + 1755
    21  UIKit                               0x000000010d63673f -[UIApplication workspaceDidEndTransaction:] + 188
    22  FrontBoardServices                  0x0000000116052d7b FrontBoardServices + 163195
    23  FrontBoardServices                  0x0000000116053118 FrontBoardServices + 164120
    24  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010c9430f1 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION** + 17
    25  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010c938eac __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 556
    26  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010c938363 __CFRunLoopRun + 867
    27  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010c937d78 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 488
    28  UIKit                               0x000000010d636091 -[UIApplication _run] + 402
    29  UIKit                               0x000000010d63a79b UIApplicationMain + 171
    30  asd                                 0x000000010c83624d main + 109
    31  libdyld.dylib                       0x000000010f3a0a05 libdyld.dylib + 10757
    32  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)

Comment: What exception are you getting?

Answer (score 2):

Try using SCNAction.  Or making sure the audio file name is correct.

```
    let source = SCNAudioSource(fileNamed: "SoundFile.mp3")
    let action = SCNAction.playAudio(source!, waitForCompletion: true)
    node.runAction(action)
```